# Alert Dialog dissmissing after clicking "Positive Button"

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-alertdialog, dismiss

I am creating custom alert dialog. The problem is- I am not calling dialogInterface.dismiss(); in setPositiveButton() method 
still my dialog is getting dismissed after clicking the positive button. So, I am unable to perform further operation with it.

Why is it happening and how can I make "positive" button do the stuff.

```
public void changePassword() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();

    View alertChangePassLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.change_password_alertdialog_layout, null);

    final EditText oldPasswordET = alertChangePassLayout.findViewById(R.id.old_password_ET_alert_dialog);
    final EditText newPasswordET = alertChangePassLayout.findViewById(R.id.new_password_ET_alert_dialog);
    final EditText confirmNewPasswordET = alertChangePassLayout.findViewById(R.id.confirm_new_password_ET_alert_dialog);
    Button changePasswordButton = alertChangePassLayout.findViewById(R.id.change_password_BB_alert_dialog);



    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(dialog_activity.this);

    alertBuilder.setTitle("Change Password");

    // Set view of xml inside alert dialog
    alertBuilder.setView(alertChangePassLayout);


    // disable dismiss dialog when clicked outside the dialog
    alertBuilder.setCancelable(false);

    // Set positive button
     alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

             Toast.makeText(dialog_activity.this, "Submit button..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             // do work here

         }
     });

    // Set negative button
    alertBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Toast.makeText(dialog_activity.this, "Cancel button..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply "do the stuff" where you have a comment saying "do work here."

```
// Set positive button
 alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

         Toast.makeText(dialog_activity.this, "Submit button..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         // do work here

     }
 });
```

Run whatever you need within that block; after it executes, the dialog is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

`positiveButton` always dismiss the dialog after the execution of the listener body.